# jaredatch metaboxes on video post formats

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to get a metabox to show up only when the video post formats is selected using jaredatch metaboxes https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Display-Options

If I select post as post type the box is applied to all posts. I've tried combos with 'show on' but none seem to target video format.

Comment: Your Question would greatly improve with a link to "jaredatch" and posting the code you are already using. See the page [ask] for some tips. You can [edit] your Q whenever needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the post format using [`get_post_format()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format).  So try adding your textarea custom field in a custom metabox library file, and then do the following:

```
if( 'video' == get_post_format( $post->ID ) ) {
    include_once( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path-to-cmb-library/video-metabox-file.php' );
}
```

This assumes that you're in The Loop or that you have a WordPress Post object in `$post`.